# Visual Studio Installer not detecting MSHTML

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio Installer to help create a installer. It has worked fine until now. Now for some reason MSHTML.dll is not being detected as a dependencies when I rebuild and on top of it removes all references to MSHTML for my solution basically cause me a file missing exception every time I try to run in the compiler. This is the second solution this has done it to me and I really don't want to do this to a third.

Comment: Can you create a small example that reproduces the problem? Then post some details of the example here?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't how to recreate the problem. I simply rebuilt Visual Studio Installer Project that once worked fine. This was after I should say I repaired VS 2010 before this and that could have caused some issued.

Comment: What happens if you create an installer for a project that's just a class library, with no code, that references MSHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL I was using was the problem. I rewrote the DLL and reattached it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Visual Studio installer projects are fundamentally broken and their dependency resolver is a buggy mess.  I've wasted hours upon hours in trying to get the dependencies to resolve correctly, and sometimes it just doesn't work.

In the end, I usually end up manually added missing DLL references (like MSHTML) into the installer project.  This will sometimes give you a warning about duplicate files (because it sort of recognizes the dependency), but it is better than the DLL not getting deployed.

The better long term solution is to not use the Visual Studio installer projects, and use something like Wix or InnoSetup or NSIS, but they are all very complicated to setup.